# Se puede sacar una columna de una matriz en java?

Tags: java, matriz

Por ejemplo tengo una matriz de tipo String y en ella almaceno nombres y numeros, mi pregunta es como se puede extraer la columna que tiene almacenados los valores numericos para utilizarlos en una suma, son dos columnas una con todos los nombres de arriba hacia abajo y la otra que van todos los numeros de igual manera de arriba hacia abajo, he investigado algo y los ejemplos que me encuentro es cuando la matriz es de tipo int pero la que yo ocupo es String y no hallo que hacer, me imagino extraer los valores de la segunda columna, almacenarlos en una variable, convertirlos y finalmente utilizarlos pero no se como hacer eso alguna ayuda porfavor?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Deberías mostrar un ejemplo del código, para poder ubicarnos mejor.

Answer (score 0):

como indicas que tienes 2 filas y los numeros se encuentran en la segunda fila, entonces en un `nuevoArreglo` de tipo int guardamos la segunda fila IMPORATNTE en el siguiente codigo recuerda cambiar solo  `columnas` por el numero de columnas que tenga tu matriz , saludos

```
int nuevoArreglo[]=new int[columnas];//cambiar "columnas"
int nroAgregar;
for(int i=0; i<columnas;i++){//cambiar "columnas"
    nroAgregar = Integer.parseInt(matriz[0][i]);
    nuevoArreglo[i]=nroAgregar;
}
```